# When a non-food product (e.g. shampoo) is labelled as "vegan", does this imply that no ingredients were tested on animals?

Tags: veganism, animal-experimentation

Various products including shampoos are labelled as "vegan" or "vegan-friendly". Does this exclude their containing ingredients tested on animals?

(I have read [this question and answer](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/931/are-cosmetics-which-are-tested-on-animals-vegan) and am aware that those who describe themselves as vegan do not use products that were tested on animals, but my question is different. It is about labelling practice.)

Comment: To me, what that question and answer indicate is that the person who wrote it and a particular vegan organization—the Vegan Society—do not view products tested on animals as vegan. They don't necessarily represent what every single vegan person thinks. Do note that the original definition of veganism, as defined by that same Vegan Society, only mentioned avoiding animal products and food and animal commodities.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - The original definition of the word "veganism" by Donald Watson and the Vegan Society was that "_Veganism is a way of living that seeks to exclude, as far as possible and practicable, all forms of exploitation of, and cruelty to, animals for food, clothing and any other purpose_". That covers more than just farming and butchering. You could post a question to Meta if you wanted.

Comment: I believe that what I gave was their original definition from their first manifesto in 1944, as indicated on the appropriate Wikipedia page, and the quote that you gave represents a modification of their stated position dating from 1988 or thereabouts. Regardless, my primary point is independent of that, and is that the position of any one group, even the Society that originally coined the term, does not and cannot represent the only perspective—as the answer to this question amply demonstrates.

Comment: Yes they have changed the wording over the years. Have you got a detailed source? I strongly doubt their orientation has for a single moment been compatible with the notion of the acceptability of, say, vivisection or "Lethal Dose 50" for medical or cosmetics research etc. Can you point to a person who describes themselves as vegan and who supports vivisection?

Comment: It seems to me that the question is more "Can you point to a person who describes themself as vegan and believes that a product whose research and development involved  testing on animals could be vegan, independent of whether its production and use is ethical"? And I could respond in the affirmative to that question, quite trivially....

Comment: Just to give an example, the effectiveness and safety of the Moderna and Pfizer COVID-19 vaccines has been extensively tested on mice, with the accompanying abuses and deaths. And while I certainly respect the opinion of those for whom that makes the vaccines not vegan—and even more so people who say that makes their R&D process unethical even if they are vegan—and the choices they have made in that regard, myself and a number of other people I know who identify as vegan have gotten numerous doses.

Comment: OK, thanks. You know some people describing themselves as vegan who knowingly choose to consume products that were developed using cruelty to animals. I don't know why you think that answer is trivial. I don't know who you are or anything about you, but I fully accept that what you say may well be accurate. Let's leave it there, anyway.

Comment: It's trivial because I am vegan and I believe exactly what I wrote: that what makes a product vegan is whether it contains animal products. I also don't use cosmetics whose R&D involved experimentation on animals (particularly the type that you mentioned), but that is a separate albeit related moral position. I *have* been vaccinated against COVID-19, despite the fact that those vaccines were developed with methods that did include animal experimentation. I thought that was clear from my comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Humane Society of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humane_Society_of_the_United_States) has produced an infographic showing the meaning of labels related to animal products and animal testing on **cosmetics** items specifically:

[image]

Source: [Humane Society of the United States](https://www.humanesociety.org/sites/default/files/docs/how-to-read-cosmetics-label.pdf).

In short, no, vegan labelling only indicates that a product does not contain animal-based ingredients, and **does not guarantee that it was not tested on animals**.

Comment: Thanks, even if the answer is disappointing. At least the leaping bunny badge awarded by Cruelty Free International gives the guarantee I need. This is strange because the product that occasioned my question was a bottle of Garnier shampoo. Its labelling says it's vegan, but all it says about animal testing is that since 1989 Garnier has been "committed to a world without animal testing". That doesn't in itself mean the company doesn't sell products that were tested on animals. And the bottle doesn't carry the LB logo either. Yet Garnier does have LB certification and seems fine on this score.